# Android - ListView only show the first result

Tags: android, listview, element

I am working on an android app which interacts with Twitter using their search API.
Everythings works well except that when I want to show the result using a ListView, only the first result is shown.

```
ArrayList<TwitterJSONResults> arrayList = new ArrayList<TwitterJSONResults>(data.getResults().size());
for (int i = 0; i < data.getResults().size(); i++) {
    arrayList.add(data.getResults().get(i));
}

ArrayAdapter<TwitterJSONResults> resultAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<TwitterJSONResults>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
listview.setAdapter(resultAdapter);
resultAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

The code snippet above show how I add the results to the adapter and set this adapter to the the listview, What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What sais LogCat about arrayList.size()?

Comment: That I have n elements (around 15), it even prints them all correctly!

Comment: Thats probably not the problem but you do not have to call resultAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(). Mh well..the list consists of 15 items but only the first one is shown..and also the first one is shown correctly? Do you override toString() in TwitterJSONResults class?

Comment: Yes the first one shown correctly and I override toString(). Everything should work fine but I dont understand why it's not! I even checked the size of the ArrayAdapter and it's the right one.

Comment: How does your layout look like? ListViews should always set to fill_parent or sized via weight param. Or maybe you put your ListView inside of a ScrollView..or maybe your ListView has not enough space..dunno. Paste the layout

Comment: Exactly ! I had the listview inside a scrollview ! damn I feel stupid now. Can you write that as an answer so I can "accept" it.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Don't put ListView inside of a ScrollView :)

Comment: Ok, but now I've lost scrolling!  My view consists of a LinearLayout that includes a ListView.  The ListView itself can be scrolled, but the LinearLayout can't, so the items in the LinearLayout beyond the ListView can't be viewed - depending on the size of the user's screen.    I guess one should never include items after a ListView within a layout!

Comment: If you're still looking for a solution, http://nex-otaku-en.blogspot.com/2010/12/android-put-listview-in-scrollview.html provides a method of fixing the height of the ListView so it will display all items.

Comment: Thank You ! I've been looking for this :)

Answer (score 44):

You can use ListView in ScrollView.

```
public class Utility {
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter == null) {
        // pre-condition
        return;
    }

    int totalHeight = 0;
    int desiredWidth = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
        listItem.measure(desiredWidth, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();
}
}
```

Call this function right after you change ListView items, like that:

```
Utility.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(myListView);
```

Read [source](http://kennethflynn.wordpress.com/2012/09/12/putting-android-listviews-in-scrollviews).

Comment: Thank you. I have a slide out menu that will not scroll properly without a scrollview. This solution worked for the rare instance I couldn't avoid it.

Comment: you saved a life buddy :)

Comment: Amazing thank you, Any idea why the screen automatically scroll to the bottom after calling that function?

Comment: @iProgrammer Thanks. it is working to me.Great solution for me

Comment: Didn't even need to think. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

Thanks to @207 I realized that the problem in my case was because I was using **NestedScrollView**, so for me the solution was used

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

Here my code:

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: This helped me!

Answer (score 5):

I have had this error like you when put listview inside ScrollView. And my solution is following as:

**1. Create a custom listview which is non scrollable**

```
public class NonScrollListView extends ListView {

public NonScrollListView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
public NonScrollListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}
public NonScrollListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}
@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int heightMeasureSpec_custom = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec_custom);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
        params.height = getMeasuredHeight();    
}
```

}

**2. Use above custom class for xml file**

```
  <xx.xx.NonScrollListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_nonscroll_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </xx.xx.NonScrollListView>
```

It worked well on all OS-version for me.
Hope best for you.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out I had everything in my java code working perfectly. the issue was that was using the listview **inside** a scrollview which is generally a bad idea. It led to listview ignoring

```
android:layout="wrap_content"
```

therefore the content was there, it just was not showing. After I remove the scrollview from my XML file, everything worked file.

Big thanks to 207 for the support :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ListView inside a NestedScrollView.
The only thing you have to remember is to add `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"` in the xml layout in order to enable the scroll of NestedScrollView's children.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in ListView xml layout

```
    android:stackFromBottom="true"
    android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my answere

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <ListView
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:id="@+id/listViewRefeCalendarDay" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```